# Using Kakutani's Theorem to prove that reflexivity is invariant under homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I was reviewing an exercise which is

**Exercise:** Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces and suppose that $T:E \to F$ is an homeomorphism. Show that if $E$ is reflexive, then $F$ is reflexive.

I already did the exercise using the definition of reflexivity (evaluation map $J:E \to E^{\ast\ast}$ is surjective), but I was willing to rewrite using Kakutani's Theorem:

**Kakutani's Theorem:** The unit closed ball is weakly compact iff the space is reflexive.

I couldn't write it down, I was wondering if you could help me. I tried something along the lines:

- $T$ is continuous, so it is weakly continuous (the same for the inverse).
- $T(\overline{B_E})$ is weakly compact.
- Try to insert $\overline{B_F}$, which is weakly closed, inside an $n\overline{B_E}$ for some $n$ and finish.

but as you can see, I couldn't close the argument.

**EDIT:** The question is answered in the comments below the accepted one. The full exercise has many claims and this was one of them. However, for this particular question the linearity is needed as @treedetective points out. Assuming this, @triple_sec's solution is correct. We concluded that there was an ambiguity in the question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T^{-1}$ is continuous, it is also bounded: there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|T^{-1}(y)\|\leq n\|y\|$  for any $y\in F$.

Pick any $y\in\overline{B_F}$ and let $x\equiv T^{-1}(y)\in E$. Then, $$\|x\|=\|T^{-1}(y)\|\leq n\|y\|\leq n,$$ so that $x\in n\overline{B_E}$. Therefore, $y=T(x)\in T(n\overline{B_E})=nT(\overline{B_E})$, the last equality stemming from linearity.

It follows that $\overline{B_F}\subseteq nT(\overline{B_E})$.

Comment: I feel the word "isomorphism" was wrong, the exercise only gives "topological isomorphism", hence my edit for the word "homeomorphism". I don't think we could suppose T linear here, but thanks for the input.

Comment: $T$ needs to be linear, otherwise the exercise is not true. By Kadets' Theorem, all separable Banach spaces are topologically equivalent. This means, for example, that $c_0$ and $\ell_2$ are topologically equivalent, but only $l_2$ is reflexive. You can find Kadets' article here: http://testuvannya.com.ua/M.I.Kadets/PDF/K-1967-1.pdf

Comment: @treedetective By “topologically equivalent,” do you mean homeomorphic (via a possibly non-linear transformation)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. To be more precise, all infinite dimensional separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. Torunczyk generalized the "separability" assumption and proved that any two infinite dimensional Banach spaces with the same density character are homeomorphic. Another interesting result of the same philosophy, is that every infinite dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to its closed unit ball and to its closed unit sphere.

Comment: @treedetective So by "topological isomorphism" the exercise requires linearity? I am probably confused because of the term.

Comment: @J.Sparrow I agree with you that I, too, would interpret “topological isomorphism” as a homeomorphism without any reference to linearity. However, the exercise might assume that linearity goes without saying given the functional-analytic context.

Comment: Given the functional analytic context, the term "isomorphism" would be the best. One may even say "linear isomorphism" to avoid ambiguity, although the word "linear" is redundant and most authors omit it. But by saying "topological isomorphism" the author clearly means "homeomorphism". There is no other reason to use the word "topological" in order to describe an isomorphism, other than to distinguish it from the other type of isomorphisms that we know (the linear ones). So the formulation of the exercise is not correct. It should say plain "isomorphism" instead.